# Total/Gaussian curvature is intrinsic, yet mean curvature is extrinsic, why?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, definition, surfaces, curvature

What characteristics define the total/mean curvature to be intrinsic/extrinsic accordingly? What is different geometrically about these curvatures that cause them to be defined as this?

Comment: As you've seen, mean curvature is characterized by the derivative of areas of nearby surfaces, which is "extrinsic"; The Gaussian curvature is characterized by the area of a triangle and its excess, which can be measured intrinsiclly. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea seems to be that Gaussian curvature is *intrinsic* because it is invariant over isometric embedding.  That is, if you apply an [isometric embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Riemannian_geometry) to a surface, the mean curvature of the result may be different (making mean curvature an *extrinsic* property), but the Gaussian curvature (and any other intrinsic measurement) would have to remain the same.

Comment: "Isometric embedding" -> "local isometry"...? :)

Comment: @user86418 intrinsic properties are those that stay the same under isometries (AKA isometric embeddings or isometric isomorphisms).  In general, a "local isometry" may change some intrinsic property of the manifold.

Comment: "Isometric embedding" reads strangely here, since $S$ is/might be already embedded. "Isometry" would sound fine. But note, incidentally, that Gaussian curvature _is_ invariant under local isometries (though of course total curvature need not be).

Answer (score 4):

I like to point out that you can find out these numbers, at the origin only, for $z = a x^2 + b y^2.$ The Hessian matrix of second partials is diagonal, and the first derivatives are zero (at the origin only). The Gauss curvature is, say, one quarter  the determinant, $ab.$ If we flip it upside down,  $z = -a x^2 - b y^2,$ we get  $(-a)(-b)= ab$ which is unchanged.

Meanwhile, the mean curvature of the original is $a+b$ or half of that, depends on the author. If we flip it upside down, it is $-a-b,$ which is not the same as the original.

There are always choices of constants; worth working this out on your own.