# Mean curvature is extrinsic measure

Tags: differential-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Mean curvature is 1/2 of the trace of the shape operator, the shape operator can be found through a multiplication of the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
 E& F\\ 
 F&G 
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
e & f\\ 
 f& g
\end{pmatrix}
$ and $e,f,g$ can be found through the derivatives of the first fundamental form, so they are intrinsic. How is the Mean curvature an extrinsic measure then ?
The multiplication and addition of intrinsic values isn't necessary intrinsic ?

Comment: First derivatives of an intrinsic tensors are not necessarily intrinsic.  Only covariant derivatives are.  

Consider a cylindrical piece of paper, and a flat piece of paper. They can be transformed one into the other without changing the first fundamental form and or the Gaussian curvature (intrinsic properties). What does change is the second fundamental form. (extrinsic curvature). 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Theorema_Egregium

Comment: Here is an example that shows that the mean curvature is extrinsic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716796/total-gaussian-curvature-is-intrinsic-yet-mean-curvature-is-extrinsic-why/716931#716931

Comment: $e, f, g$ cannot be found through the derivative of $E, F, G$.

Comment: @ArcticChar yes, I understand it now , that's where my mistake was, i got confused with cristoffel symbols.

Comment: @user3257842, your comment is mostly correct, but not the first two sentences. Derivatives with respect to local coordintes of the components of an intrinsic tensor are intrinsic, because local coordinates are also intrinsic. It's just that the derivatives are not tensors, i.e., not independent of the local coordinates.